# How to get the primary keys of a self referencing table in EF6.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, primary-key, self-reference

I have got the following issue:

I have a (simplified) entity that is self referencing like this:

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedById {get; set; }
    public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

...with the following FluentAPI:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
    HasKey( k => k.Username );

modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
    HasOptional( x => x.ModifiedBy ).
    WithMany().
    HasForeignKey( x => x.ModifiedById );
```

...and it works. Then I have a method to get the primary keys of any entity:

```cs
public IEnumerable<EdmMember> GetPrimaryKeys( DbContext Db, DbEntityEntry Entry )
    ObjectContext objectContext = ( (IObjectContextAdapter)Db ).ObjectContext;

    MethodInfo methodInfo = objectContext.GetType().GetMethod("CreateObjectSet", new Type[] { } );
    methodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod( Entry.Entity.GetType() );
    object objectSet = methodInfo.Invoke(objectContext, null); // null in combination with self referencing entity

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = objectSet.GetType().GetProperty("EntitySet");
    EntitySet entitySet = (EntitySet) propertyInfo.GetValue(objectSet, null);

    return entitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers;
}
```

Each individually works for me, but when I try to get the primary keys of a self referencing entity I get an error, because `objectSet` becomes `null`.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why can't you use DataAnnotations?

Comment: @Chandru As far as I know it is impossible to realize this with DataAnnotations and all my attempts confirmed that.